# How do i display list items from php array

Tags: php, html, foreach, navigation

Ive been trying make this display as html list items it just a string that i explode then loop over each item i cant get it to out put correctly. Could some one please show me where im going wrong or suggest an new approch.
this is what ive tried

```
$path = "1/2/3/4";

$expath =  explode("/",$path);

$ret = '';

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($expath as $pitem) {
echo '<li><a href='.$ret .= $pitem. "/".'>'.$pitem.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

.

Desired out put on hrefs

```
1
1/2
1/2/3
1/2/3/4
```

Desired visual out LIs

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

Output i get be warned

- 1
- 1
  2/>2
- 1
  2/>2
  3/>3
- 1
  2/>2
  3/>3
  4/>4

Comment: I guess you have an extra "=" sign in the `'.$ret .= $pitem. "/".'`. Wrap it with quotes, like `'.$ret .'='. $pitem. "/".'` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$path = "1/2/3/4";
$expath = explode("/", $path);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($expath as $i => $pitem) {
    $slice = array_slice($expath, 0, $i + 1);
    $path = implode('/', $slice);
    echo '<li><a href="' . $path . '">' . $pitem . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: @user2914191 is see now that what i tried just wasn't enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `$ret`. Place that inside the loop. In your code you concatenate `$pitem` with `$ret` all older `$ret` values also get concat.

Try

```
<?php

$path = "1/2/3/4";

$expath =  explode("/",$path);


echo '<ul>';
foreach ($expath as $pitem) {
    $ret = '';

    echo '<li><a href='.$ret .= $pitem. "/".'>'.$pitem.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

If you want `=` sign tobe there in the url then just change `echo` by following

```
 echo "<li><a href='$ret=$pitem/'>$pitem</a></li>";
```

PHP `echo` with `double quotes` will print variable value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = explode("/", "1/2/3/4");
```

This will create an array $list as:

```
echo $list[0]; // 1
echo $list[1]; // 2
echo $list[2]; // 3
echo $list[3]; // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem: `echo '<li><a href='.$ret .= $pitem. "/".'>'.$pitem.'</a></li>';`

Should be formatted like:

```
echo "<li><a href='{$ret}={$pitem}/'>{$pitem}</a></li>";
```

or `echo '<li><a href="'.$ret.'='.$pitem.'/">'.$pitem.'</a></li>';`